# Cache Refresh- Cron Job Command?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

Very often Magento required Cache "Refresh" to be done.
I am looking for a **Cron Job Command** for Magento Cache **"Refresh".**
I need to Refresh cache and not Clear them.

To **"Clear"** cache, Cron job command I got is: **rm -rf /home/hosting/html/var/cache/***

Whats the command for refresh ?

---

The main blog I always need to Refresh is "BLOCK_HTML"
I would like to set a cron job for it, every 15 minutes

Answer (score 2):

n98 MageRun would be perfect for this. Just add a cron entry for

```
magerun cache:clean block_html
```

However, you would be out of your mind if you did this on a production store. You should never clear the cache, instead let it expire naturally.

In which case, you could achieve the same by extending the core and overriding the behaviour of `Mage_Core_Model_Cache` and altering the behaviour of the `getCacheLifetime()` method to be hard coded to 15 minutes.

I wouldn't do this either though, however I'm sure you have a compelling reason to want to do something so severe.

Comment: Often when I log in I see a message Cache Refreshis required. Where can I control the expiration time of this message?

Comment: Ignore the message :)